# Need help designing a database - users and projects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, database-design, sql-server-2012

I have a two tables **users** and **project**, in **master_db**, which store user details and project details respectively.

I would like to solve a problem:

***I have an .aspx page which will allow me to 'manage' a project, adding users and assigning them roles. I would like to know how to create a table(s) that will allow me to add/remove a 'user' to a 'project'.***

I was thinking of creating a **user_project** table that stores the **user_id** and **project_id**

Do you have any ideas or other solutions to the problem ?

Comment: Such is the point of using [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). Is there any specific issue you've been facing while implementing this?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. This is called the "junction" (or "link") table, and has a key that is the combination of keys migrated from the two tables involved in the many-to-many relationship. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE user_project (
    user_id int REFERENCES users (user_id),
    project_id int REFERENCES project (project_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, project_id)
)
```

*(Note that tables are by default [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) under MS SQL Server, unless you explicitly use NONCLUSTERED keyword with your PRIMARY KEY, which is probably OK in this case.)*

This is indeed the "standard" way to represent such a relationship. Tell me more about the role of the "role" ;) and I might have some suggestions how to handle that too...

Comment: Thanks! Just a side-question.. Is there a way how to choose two primary keys within MS SQL Server 2012 GUI ?

Comment: @Brian You mean SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: yes, the 2012 version.

Comment: @Brian Unfortunately I don't have it in front of me and my memory is a bit fuzzy on that, so I can't give you the exact click-by-click instructions, but I do remember it's plainly visible in the UI. Try searching around  a little (right-click on the table and see what you get) and I'm sure you'll find it in no time! Alternatively, just use the DDL SQL ;) BTW, this is not "two primary keys", this is one composite primary key consisting from two fields. You can have one primary (PRIMARY KEY) and multiple alternate keys (UNIQUE constraint) per table.

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to do a bit more than that I think.  For example, you could have user #33, which has role #4 on project #88, while on project #74, he has role #2.  Does that sound something like the user would want?

If a user will always have the same role, then you solution is correct.

If not you will have to add a role_id to user_project.

So I would have user_project that is a user_id, project_id, and role_id.  The PK for this table would be (user_id, project_id).

Comment: That means I will have to create another table 'role' with role_id and role_name right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would have a User table that has information relating only to the user (name, email, whatever), a project table relating only to the project, and then a third table "Project Users" that would hold foreign keys to both User and Project tables (userID, projectID), along with any other necessary columns like "role", "access level", etc... that relates only to the relationship between user and project.  The primary key in the "Project Users" table would be a combination of the two foreign keys.

You could have a table of security levels, a table of roles, etc... where you would stick PK from those tables into the "role" or "security level" column of your "Project Users" table...

Hope that helps...